# post json in android annotations

Tags: android, rest, android-annotations

I want to use @Rest api from android annotations to post application/json data to server. 
How can I do it?
I want something like [POST request send json data java HttpUrlConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404252/post-request-send-json-data-java-httpurlconnection) but as simple as android annotations.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can user [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) Type-safe REST client for Android and Java.

Use annotations to describe the HTTP request:

- URL parameter replacement and query parameter

support Object

- conversion to request body (e.g., JSON, protocol buffers)
- Multipart    request body and file upload

See here a good tutorial [Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit)

Comment: thanks, wow it seems to be such a good library. I'm going to use it. thanks

Comment: yes it is a great lib I have used a lot in my app. You're welcome!
If you can accept the answer =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library for this. [Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fkylewbanks.com%2Fblog%2FTutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON&ei=b4_9VOvMC5GR7Aabm4HAAw&usg=AFQjCNFbFjT77J7XWlrdKuwRB5cNXKSl_w&sig2=0f-dJjlvpfpC1LzfrnbuJw) and [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html) you can find useful tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Actually i think this is well documented in the [AA wiki](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest%20API#post).

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "http://company.com/ajax/services", converters = { GsonHttpMessageConverter.class })
public interface MyRestClient {

  @Post("/events")
  void addEvent(Event event);
}

public class Event {
  String description;

  // ...
}
```

You you can use `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` instead of `GsonHttpMessageConverter` if you are using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/) instead of [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson).

> Disclaimer: i am an AndroidAnnotations developer.

Comment: Could you tell me why you cannot use post with a set of arguments in the same way as Retrofit or a GET request? Why does AA have the need for a Post arguments class?

Comment: Post parameter annotation is added in the next release of AA. If you need new features, feel free to contribute, as all AA developers do in their free time.

Comment: I didn't want to come off as needy and if I did, I apologize. You do great work with AA! Thank you very much for your good work and your quick response.