# How to update element value in JsonObject?

Tags: java, android, json

I have a json file with parameters `name` and `hit`.

```
[{
    "name": "pavan",
    "hit": true   
}]
```

I would like to update `name` and `hit` to

```
[{
    "name": "sai",
    "hit": false
}]
```

I tried using `put` but it is not updating the values.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

      /*  x = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        y = new ArrayList<String>();*/
        try {
            URL url=new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1854yb");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line="";
            while (line!=null)
            {
                line=bufferedReader.readLine();
                data=data+line;
            }
            JSONArray JA=new JSONArray(data);
            for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject JO= (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
                singleparsed="Name:"+JO.get("name")+"\n"+
                        "Hit:"+JO.get("hit");

                JO.put("name","sai");
                JO.put("hit",false);

                dataparsed=dataparsed+singleparsed;
            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I want to update any element in that file, but it's not working.

Comment: How do you know it's not working? By looking at `singleparsed`? If so, it's normal,  you need to move it after the lines where you put the new values.

Comment: Yeah you were right but its not updating in link why??

Comment: Well, then show us all the code; here you are just creating a copy to the `JO` object with the new values, but you are not using it, nor publishing it back to the url.

Comment: this was the code and to post it back what to do?? Thanks

Comment: That's entirely another question; see [Android-POST Json with HttpUrlConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40238360)

Comment: i have gone through that but i didnt get where to use that method in above code??please help

Answer (score 1):

You can override the value as you want putting the same key.

```
[ { "name": "pavan", "hit": true } ]

JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonObject();
jsonObj .put("name", "Sai");
jsonObj .put("hit", false);
```

Comment: this is not working kindly see the above code my JSONOBJECT name is JO and i am doing same but its not working??

Comment: make another object.   JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonObject();
jsonObj .put("name", "Sai");
jsonObj .put("hit", false); jsonArray.put(jsonObj);

Answer (score 0):

We can use JSON Object request instead of String request in Volley.

```
JSONObject obj = JSONObject()
obj.put("name", "xxx")
obj.put("hit", false)

Log.i("OutPut : ",obj.toString())
```

Comment: can you please elaborate i didnt get you

Comment: Actually you need to change dynamic param know.?

Comment: JsonObject obj = JsonObject()
obj.put("name", "xxx")
obj.put("hit", false)

Log.i("OutPut : ",obj.toString())

Comment: its not working i think its not JsonObject JSONObject i tried this and why are you creating new jsonobject i mean the jsonobject is changing right??