# How to post Json Object as a Value using Asynctask?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-asynctask

I want to post below json data using `AsyncTask`... My Problem is that I have key called as `dynamic_fields` values are `JSON Format` But it's storing as String Format

**Example JSON data**

```
{
 "createdDate": Fri Mar 15 12:00:59 GMT+05:30 2019,
 "UID": "",
 "role": "manager",
 "webMenu": [],
 "mobileMenu": {},
 "isAdmin": false,
 "isDeleted": false,
 "tasks": {
   "tasks": 0,
   "inProgress": 0,
   "total": 0
 },
 "dynamic_fields": {
   "location": "Hyderabad",
   "area": "KPHB"
 }
}
```

**Below screenshot of Format changing JSON to String In the firebase**
[image]

**My AsyncTask**

```
 private void createEmployee() {

       employeeDetails.put("email", email);
       employeeDetails.put("phoneNumber", mobile);
       employeeDetails.put("firstName", firstName);
       employeeDetails.put("lastName", "-");
       employeeDetails.put("photoUrl", photoUrl);
       employeeDetails.put("isManager", isManager);
       employeeDetails.put("OID", OID);
       employeeDetails.put("MID", userId);
       employeeDetails.put("address", "-");

       if (hashMap_dynamicForms != null && hashMap_dynamicForms.size() >0) {

           JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(hashMap_dynamicForms);
           employeeDetails.put("dynamic_fields", jsonObject);
       }
       Log.e("data", employeeDetails+"");
       new SignupAsynTask().execute();
   }
```

---

```
class SignupAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           super.onPreExecute();
       }

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           RegisterUser_Signup objreg = new RegisterUser_Signup();
           HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
         //  ArrayList<Object> arrays = new ArrayList<>();
          // arrays.add(employeeDetails);
           String result = null;
           try {
               result = objreg.sendPostRequest(RequestUrl, employeeDetails);
           }catch (Exception e) {
               Log.d("Exception", "errortaskcare" + e.getMessage());
           }
           return result;
       }
       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
           super.onPostExecute(s);
           hideProgressDialg(Create_NewEmployee.this);
           if (s.contains("Error Registering")) {
               Toast.makeText(Create_NewEmployee.this, "Error, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               return;
           } else {

           }
       }
   }
```

**Method of sendPostRequest**

```
public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                                 HashMap<String, Object> postDataParams) {

       URL url;
       String response = "";
       try {
           url = new URL(requestURL);

           HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
           conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
           conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
           conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
           conn.setDoInput(true);
           conn.setDoOutput(true);


           OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
           BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                   new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
           writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

           writer.flush();
           writer.close();
           os.close();
           int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

           if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
               BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
               response = br.readLine();
           }
           else {
               response="Error Registering";
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return response;
   }

   private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, Object> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
       StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
       boolean first = true;
       for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : params.entrySet()){
           if (first)
               first = false;
           else
               result.append("&");

           result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
           result.append("=");
           result.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
       }

       return result.toString();
   }
```

Comment: have u checked this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404252/post-request-send-json-data-java-httpurlconnection

Comment: Can you post asyc task execution related code?

Comment: @NileshRathod tried sir not working

Comment: @ShripadJadhav ya sure i will post it

Comment: @ShripadJadhav i posted my code please check it once bro