# Java Eclipse HttpUrlConnection Post request with JSON Body authentication

Tags: java, json, eclipse, post, httpurlconnection

I tried and still trying to write Java code in Eclipse to call HttpUrl and gererate token and with the help of token I will call another URL to get data. I have tried it in Postman and its working there. Now I am writing java code to replicate whole Postman process. I tried to follow many ways and [Stackoverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404252/post-request-send-json-data-java-httpurlconnection) but not getting data.Below is Postman steps.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your HTTP POST code?

As per your postman images, I think the API uses HTTPS and you're using `HttpURLConnection`.

You can try using `HttpsURLConnection` and give it a shot.

Hope it was useful.

Have a Nice Day :)